# Limits and Order Proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification

Suppose $a_n -> l$ and $b_n -> m$. If $a_n \leq b_n$ for all $n \geq N_0$, then $l \leq m$.

My lecturer did the proof using contradiction but I wanted to see if my proof was valid.

There exists a natural number $N_1$ such that for all $n > N_1$, |$a_n - l$| < $\epsilon$
There exists a natural number $N_2$ such that for all $n > N_2$, |$b_n - m$| < $\epsilon$

Let $\epsilon$ > 0 be arbitrary. Let $N$ = max{$N_1,N_2$}. For all $n > N$, observe that $a_n > l - \epsilon$, and $b_n < m + \epsilon$.

Now, by hypothesis, note that $l-\epsilon$ < $a_n$ \leq $b_n$ < $m + \epsilon$.

$=>$ $l-m < 2\epsilon$, since $\epsilon$ > 0, deduce that $l-m \leq 0$, so $l \leq m$ as required.

Comment: Strictly speaking you should define $N = \max{N_0, N_1, N_2}$ else you can't use that $a_n \leq b_n$. For the rest it looks good to me.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry that was a silly error, $N_0$ for the original condition. Thanks for responding buddy : ) @Ronald